# Abstract Factory with two different model DB's

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I'm using a Abstract FactoryPattern with two different DB Models (Oracle and DB2), according with this pattern I have to implement all of the methods for each factoryDAo, but I don't want to have the methods of Oracle in my FactoryDao DB2, because the DB model it's different.

Now the question is, what is the best practice in this case, how I have to implement this pattern to isolate both models?

**FACTORY**

```
    public abstract class DAOFactory {

        public static final int ORACLE = 1;

        public static final int DB2 = 2;

public abstract ApplicationDAO getApplicationDAO() throws HibernateException;
.
.


    public static DAOFactory getDAOFactory(int factory) {
            switch (factory) {

            case ORACLE:
                return new OracleFactoryDao();

            case DB2:
                return new Db2FactoryDao();
                }
            return null;
        }
```

**FACTORYDAO**

```
 public class OracleFactoryDao extends DAOFactory {

public ApplicationDAOImpl getApplicationDAO() {
        return new ApplicationDAOImpl();
    }
..}

    public class DB2FactoryDao extends DAOFactory {
public ApplicationDAOImpl getApplicationDAO() {
        return new ApplicationDAOImpl();
    }..}
```

Comment: If the objects don't have same methods, there is no point to using a factory to create them, because they will not be able to be used interchangeably.  The whole  idea behind the factory is to return different implementations of the same interface.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer and in this case what is the correct pattern for this case?

Comment: Don't know.  Not clear what problem needs be solved.

Comment: dbugger 23 I think a solution for that, it's the answer from sab, using two interfaces, with this I can use the abstract factory pattern with different's models, what do you think about this solution?

Comment: Not sure what problem you are trying to solve.  Patterns exist to solve problems.  Explain what you are trying to accomplish, then patterns might suggest themselves.

Comment: ok, I want to use two different DB's, with differents models, in the end It will be a two different factories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two interface: IOracleFactoryDao and IDB2FactoryDao , 
where you put only the method of one of the DB.

```
 interface IOracleFactoryDao{
     void myOracleMethod();
 }
 interface IDB2FactoryDao{
     void myDB2Method();
 }
 public class OracleFactoryDao extends DAOFactory implements IOracleFactoryDao {
     void myOracleMethod(){...}
}
public class DB2FactoryDao extends DAOFactory implements IDB2FactoryDao{
     void myDB2Method(){...}
}
```